# How to perform slot validation in webhook in Dialogflow?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

How to perform slot validation in an intent using backend code (webhook).

I have seen how to perform slot filling using the webhooks but I want to know how to validate the slot data and re-prompt the user if validation fails.

> Example:
>   User: I want to know the your services in London.
>   Bot: We do not provide service in London, please enter some other city name.

Answer (score 3):

**In short:** If validation fails, reset the dialog contexts, trigger your intent again, and optionally use default values to keep other parameters that were actually valid (so you don't need to re-prompt the user for those again).

**You don't need to declare an incoming context on that intent to achieve this.** Note that you can use contexts in intents, even though they are not declared as incoming/outgoing contexts on that intent.

In this example, I'm requesting 2 parameters from the user (car `make` and `model`). Of course, `Enable webhook call for slot filling` needs to be set in your intent.

**Steps:**

1. On Dialogflow, in the intent, declare an Event. This can be used to trigger this intent from your fulfillment code:

[image]

2. In your parameters, declare a Default Value for each parameter you want to be able to keep after resetting the intent:

[image]

3. Set the Default Value to a parameter in a helper context. If this helper context does exist, the default value will be set, otherwise, it'll be kept empty. This will allow you to reset the intent and keep other parameters you already had. In this example, I'm using the context `show-car-details-data`, and setting the default value of parameter `model` to `_model` in that incoming context:

[image]

4. In your slot-filling fulfillment method, you can validate your parameter and re-prompt the user by reseting the intent. To do that, you need to 1) **clear the current dialog contexts**, 2) call `setFollowupEvent` to trigger your intent again, and 3) optionally set up some helper context you can use to assign default values (so you don't need to re-prompt user for those that were valid).
   I'm using [Dialogflow Fulfillment Node.js Library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs):

```js
// clear dialog contexts:
agent.contexts.forEach( e => {
  if ( e.name.endsWith('_id_dialog_context') ) agent.context.delete(e.name);
});
// workaround bug: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/160
agent.add('');
// set follow up event: this triggers your intent again
agent.setFollowupEvent('show-car-details');
// optionally set helper context to set default values and avoid re-prompt of already valid values
// in this example, keep make since it was a valid parameter
// clear model because it was invalid. User will be prompted again on model, but not on make
agent.context.set('show-car-details-data', 1, { '_make': make, '_model': '' });
```

Comment: problem with this approach was, if we are invoking the intent using events, we cannot prompt a message to the user, or change prompt message of empty slot/parameter.

Comment: @sid8491 I'm changing the prompt message for the second try. Like `1st try: "What day is good for you?"`, on invalid response from the user, then I prompt `2nd try: "We don't work on Sunday, choose another day"`. What do you mean you can't change the prompt?  For example, I add `agent.context.set('show-car-details-data', 1, { '_make': make, '_model': '', 'retryText': 'We don\'t sell that model.' });`, and then check for `retryText` existence to use on the intent (you can concatenate `retryText + agent.consoleMessages[0].text`, for example)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i will check this and get back to you.

Comment: I know this answer is old. I'm bit confused about 'retryText'. Is it gona substitute the parameter prompt? Any ideas how can I do this on webhook response?

Comment: @IagoCoutinhoCampos I really can't remember well enough to help here. But the idea is that you can read `show-car-details-data` context (if any), and see if `retryText` exists. It will if you set it up in the previous interaction when you detected there was a problem with user input. Then, you can invoke `agent.add(text);` with a different `text` to be prompted to user depending on the existence of `retryText` in `show-car-details-data`. For example: `if(retryText) { agent.add('Try again. ' + retryText + agent.consoleMessages[0].text); } else { agent.add( agent.consoleMessages[0].text ); }`

Answer (score 2):

Steps

1. Enable webhook for slot filing in Dialog flow with Entity set as "Required".
2. Get entity from arguments.
3. Programmatically check if it is not null and as per your requirement.
4. If it is correct, proceed further.
5. Else, **RESET THE CONTEXT** and ask the question as per the wrong slot input. Programmatically, set the output context same as input so that user can again respond back slot/entity. If the correct context is not present, the slot will not get captured. When a slot is captured as per set Entity, the context for that slot captured is finished and to recapture it you need to increase the lifespan or create it again.

Comment: Can you please clarify step 5? Perhaps with an example, or just more detail?

Comment: You will need to set the output context same as the input context for that intent.

Comment: Is it possible to do this if the intent does not have any contexts? I am asking if it's possible to avoid contexts because I'd like the intent to be invoked directly, without having to access it through another intent. For example, I'd like users to be able to say directly, "Ask Calculator Agent what is 5 plus 5" instead of something like, "Ask Calculator Agent to add two numbers", which would set the PERFORM_ADDITION context, then "5 plus 5" .

Comment: As a workaround you may create a same duplicate intent with an input context. When you want to reprompt the user, you can set intent as output intent and now when the user speaks the new intent will be called. In the webhook, you can point to same function to execute the code.

Comment: That workaround would work, though any way to do it without having to copy the intent (and remember to update both each time I need to change the intents)?

Comment: Without a copy, it would be tricky. For capturing slots, Dialogflow generates individual context for each slot. You can see that by debugging at the webhook and printing all present contexts. If validation fails, you may need to reset that individual context programmatically some how. Since it is generated randomly I am not sure how will you set it again as the name might change on each attempt.

Comment: What does the "Enable webhook call for slot filling" option in the Dialogflow Intent Fulfillment section do? I would expect it to make slot validation easy.

Comment: Yes, that will call the webhook Everytime slot needs to be filled. That is where you will need to validate and reset the dynamic context.