# How to perform slot validation in webhook in Dialogflow in Asp.net webapi using C#

Tags: c#, validation, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Have setup Diaglow flow webhook api for fetching values from database and its working fine. There are dynamic values which needs to be validated from database and error message to be displayed.
I require fulfillment(webhook) to validate the inputs and if the variable value is wrong need to throw an back error and remain on same context.
I am using Asp.net WebApi(C#) so require a example in C#. There are various examples in Python using incline editor which cannot be replicated in Asp.net webapi.

Comment: Hello, I believe it would be helpful to check [this other thread that has explained how to accomplish this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478093/how-to-perform-slot-validation-in-webhook-in-dialogflow). Maybe you will accomplish this directly from Dialogflow. At what point of the pseudo process are you stuck building this in C# ?

Comment: The shared example is useful for inline editor and not helpful in case of webhook. I am fetching values from database and cannot use inline editor.

Comment: I would recommend that you raise an issue on the [Dialogflow repo](https://github.com/dialogflow) or a GCP [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=501190&template=1169497) to ask for such examples to be added to the documentation. You could also update your question with a snippet of code of what you already tried so to make it easier for other users with C# knowledge to help you.